# How to upgrade hibernate 3 version to hibernate 5.2.10 Final version : [including jars]

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying to upgrade hibernate 3 jar with the latest version of hibernate i.e 5.2.10 in my project. But the structure of the jars changes and new jars are introduced.

Hibernate 3 jars included in my project are as follows :

```
backport-util-concurrent.jar
ehcache-1.5.0.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
```

I have downloaded the latest jars of hibernate 5.2.10 and included in my project which are as follows :

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-2.10.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.10.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
```

It results into an compilation error.
**So I just want to know what libraries/jars I have to include to upgrade hibernate 3 version to hibernate 5.2.10 Final version.**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.